# How can I console.log the name property of the objects in the shoppingCart array using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var shoppingCart = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Mens Shirt',
  price: 20,
  size: 'Large'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'kids shirt',
  price: 15,
  size: 'small'
}]
```

Comment: Hi Dean. Please do your research, and show us what you've tried when you ask questions. StackOverflow is a question and answer site, not a forum, and I know that can be confusing at first. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nothing I have tried has even really made sense to me yet, I am quite lost as to why I am posting a question on here for the first time. I have spent plenty of time researching and so far nothing is adding up. Also I tried the console.table() function and received this error, "TypeError: console.table is not a function".

Comment: So do not know how to loop over an array? Do you know how to access a property in an object? Two basic concepts combined.

Comment: I am using my coding bootcamps browser, so the console.table function is not returning as it should. But i know the for loop is the way to solve this issue and I understand for loops but it is the grabbing and outputting of the "name" property that I am having issues with. I also know to output I can use the .map() function but I haven't been able to get there as I am stuck on getting the name property out in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `Array.prototype.forEach` like this:

```js
var shoppingCart = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Mens Shirt',
  price: 20,
  size: 'Large'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'kids shirt',
  price: 15,
  size: 'small'
}]

shoppingCart.forEach(item => console.log(item.name));
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll take a further look into the functions and syntax that makes it work but I was stuck on using a for() loop instead of looking at a forEach. Thank you!